# Mapbox GL canvas size twice the size on iOS?

Tags: cordova, canvas, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

In a `cordova` applicaiton I create an instance of Mapbox GL on a `div` that's 300 x 600 pixels.

On Android the canvas that is automatically created gets a size of 300x600, but when I run the same app on iOS the canvas size is twice the size :  600x1200
This causes performance and memory problems.

Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid it ?

Comment: Can you include some code to look at? It sounds obviously like there is some issue with physical vs display pixels. How is the canvas "automatically created"? Normally you create your own `<div>` and style it to the size you want.

Comment: You will need to force the canvas to the correct size. Most likely it is mapbox-gl-js that is sizing the canvas to match the device native resolution. You will have to read the documentation and find out how you can set the canvas resolution. Or make the containing div half the size, start the app and then up the size (this may fool the lib)